# Tomcat 8 installation on windows 7. Localhost blank page

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I just have installed Tomcat 8 on my windows 7 computer but when I go on localhost I see blank page.
I write here all I've done:

- Double-click apache-tomcat-8.0.20
- Type 80 in the HTTP/1.1 Connector Port field to overwrite the default.
- Type admin in the User Name and password field.
- Type C:\PTC\Tomcat
- Navigate to C:\ptc\Tomcat\conf in Windows Explorer
- Open the server.xml file
- Replace all protocol="HTTP/1.1" with protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
- Save and close
- On Start - All programs - Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8 Select Configure Tomcat
- Click the Startup type drop-down list to expand it and select Automatic
- In Java tab append the current contents:

  -XX:+UseNUMA

  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

  -XX:PermSize=128m

  -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
- Clear all of the content in the Initial memory pool and Maximum memory pool field
- Click the Apply button.
- Start tomcat from General tab

When I go on Chrome and type
http://localhost 
I have a blank page

Comment: Make sure apache is running also show check the content in `webapps/ROOT` is there any index file ??

Answer (score 0):

Append the port no also in the url :
eg: http://localhost:port_no, by default port is 8080(http://localhost:8080)

Comment: If I do so, the browser says he can't find any page. If I do http://localhost:80, instead, it says it can't give a protected connection and "kick me out"

Comment: Please check the port no in server.xml. If the server has got started it should at least show the default homepage of tomcat. I think the issue is with port no.

Comment: Ok, I did the installation from the beginning but without changing the port from 8080 to 80 and it works now.
I'll keep the 8080

Comment: Ports below 1024 are protected by the system. Use a port > 1024 and also specify the port in  the url as already mentioned.